# How to view the website of a running Flask server that I am SSHing to?

Tags: python, web, ssh, flask

I am SSHing to a server, where Flask is set up. When I execute the flask application, the terminal says `Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/`, as is written in the file.

Is there any way to view this site on my local machine? Going to the domain above on my local machine just gives a **Site Not Found** error.

Do I need to just change the IP, or is this not possible?

Comment: What happens when you go to `http://<IP_you_SSH'd_to>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Internet Protocol Version 4, the address 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non-applicable target...
>
> In the context of servers, 0.0.0.0 means "all IPv4 addresses on the local machine"

-- [Wikipedia: 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

Key words being "on the local machine". Which means `http://0.0.0.0:80/` is not the actual address of the server, just the address it is "listening on".

You need to use the public IP address of the server that you are accessing. If you SSH'd into this machine, you should be able to use the same IP address or hostname to access the now running webserver.